Show equality of sums of products of sinc functions
We define the following function
$$
f(k_1,k_2,k_3,k_4,k_5,k_6) = \sum_{n_1,n_2,n_3} \sqrt{n_1^2+n_2^2+n_3^2} \; \mathrm{sinc}[\pi(an_1-k_1)] \, \mathrm{sinc}[\pi(an_2-k_2)] \, \mathrm{sinc}[\pi(an_3-k_3)] \, \mathrm{sinc}[\pi(an_3-k_4)] \, \mathrm{sinc}[\pi(an_2-k_5)] \, \mathrm{sinc}[\pi(an_1-k_6)]
$$
where $k_{i}$ are integers, $a$ is real and positive and the sums runs from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ (but can be taken to run between $-N$ and $N$ for brevity sake).
Show that:
$$
f(0,k,k,k,k,k) = f(-k,k,k,k,k,k)
$$
for $k=2m$ and
$$
f(0,k,k,k,k,k) = -f(-k,k,k,k,k,k)
$$
for $k=2m+1$.

It is easy to show that only terms that have all $n_{i} \neq 0$ matter, as all others vanish identically. However, where do I start from there on?
